# Will I get in trouble for sending money to an account specified by my sugar daddy?

Tags: bank-account, scams, sugar-daddy

I met a guy on an app and we talked for about a couple of weeks. Then, he asked if he could help me with my bills and I said yes. However, he wanted information on my bank account, so I gave him my [Venmo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venmo), as it would be more convenient. He told me to take $300 and send the rest to an account that he had.

Will I get in trouble for that? I only did what he told me to do.

Comment: The trouble you'll get in is any money he sent you will be taken back (because he sent it fraudulently) and any money you sent to him you will lose.

Comment: To put it in a short way, the Venmo transfer will be undone, and you will lose your own money you sent. If your account does not cover it, you will be into overdraft. Your account may be closed and you may be questioned by law enforcement regarding money laundering.

Comment: Check out the other questions in the sugar-daddy tag: https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sugar-daddy . Your situation sounds similar to several other questions

Answer (score 9):

It's the usual scam. Nobody sends you money for free. Ever.

What will happen is that his Venmo transfer will be undone, either by him, or by Venmo when the found out it was fraud, and your money you sent him forward is gone. Because you sent it voluntarily, you will not be covered.

Of course you can sue him, but he will just disappear, and you are out of your money.

Stop believing in Santa Claus.

Comment: While I sympatize greatly with your last sentence, I am not sure it adds any value to the answer.

Comment: also you are out of your money, not put of it.

Comment: @StianYttervik It does add value. Without it, it's very easy to think they just happened to find one scam rather than that they are looking for something that definitely does not exist. If someone is making payments online and doesn't know that they should never accept money that they haven't earned or make payments at the direction of other people, they badly need to be shaken at least a bit.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz it *literally* adds nonsense. It *figuratively* is an insult. The combination is detracting from an otherwise terse and to-the-point answer. Not a large slight, for sure, but still. I +1 the answer but I stand by that it is better without the last sentence.